# Remove certain rows in multiindex series with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, series

**i want to remove all the rows that equal to 0, so only rows that equal to 4, 1, 2 and 3 remain from the series below**

```
my_series = df.groupby(by=['Continent','bins']).size()
```

my_series output:

```
Continent      bins            
Asia           (2.212, 15.753]     4
               (15.753, 29.227]    1
               (29.227, 42.701]    0
               (42.701, 56.174]    0
               (56.174, 69.648]    0
Australia      (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (15.753, 29.227]    0
               (29.227, 42.701]    0
               (42.701, 56.174]    0
               (56.174, 69.648]    0
Europe         (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (15.753, 29.227]    3
               (29.227, 42.701]    2
               (42.701, 56.174]    0
               (56.174, 69.648]    0
North America  (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (15.753, 29.227]    0
               (29.227, 42.701]    0
               (42.701, 56.174]    0
               (56.174, 69.648]    1
South America  (2.212, 15.753]     0
               (15.753, 29.227]    0
               (29.227, 42.701]    0
               (42.701, 56.174]    0
               (56.174, 69.648]    1
dtype: int64
```

*the result type must be series, not dataframe.*

i tried "dataframe-like" approach like

```
df = df[df['bins']!=0]
```

but surely this didn't work out.

and same failure here(apparently it's not applyable to a multiindex series)

```
my_series.difference(list)
```

Comment: can you provide a sample dataset for testing?

Comment: Try `my_series[my_series != 0]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `bins` has the `category` dtype when you use `groupby`, Pandas generates all combinations of `bins`, that's why you have 0 in your result.

From [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

> **observed bool, default False**
>
> This only applies if any of the groupers are Categoricals. If True: only show observed values for categorical groupers. If False: show all values for categorical groupers.

First solution based on your code, use `observed=True`:

```
my_series = df.groupby(['Continent','bins'], observed=True).size()
```

Second solution, more straightforward, use `value_counts`:

```
my_series = df.value_counts(['Continent', 'bins'])
```